# Задание : считать текстовый файл и найти в нем слово, которое встречается реже всего. Не могу понять что делать дальше

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
   rarestWord("D:/testfile.txt");
}
   static void rarestWord(String filename){
 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String str;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   //не знаю что делать дальше
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Path path = Paths.get("file");
    try {
       String word = Files.lines(path)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .get().getKey();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Почему ту используется `flatMap`? Потому что для каждого входного значения будет по выходному стриму?

Comment: да, из стрима строк, один стрим слов

Comment: добавь описание что именно используется для решения.